# Android: Widget takes too much place

Tags: android, android-widget

I faced with a strange problem with my widget size.
I decided to develop one simple widget with supporting of ldpi, mdpi, large-mdpi and hdpi screens.
At first I created xml/widget.xml where I defined the following:

```
<appwidget-provider 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:minHeight="146dip" 
    android:minWidth="220dip" 
    android:updatePeriodMillis="0" 
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget"/>
```

So I expect that my widget will take 3x2 cells for all supported screens.
Then I designed several layouts, one for each screen type - ldpi, mdpi, large-mdpi and hdpi - where:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/Widget" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 
    ... 
</RelativeLayout>
```

So I expect that the widget size will fit 3x2 cells for all screens, not more, not less. 
But currently when I run it on emulator (and real device too) I see that my widget takes 
more than a half of a screen for all supporting screens - 4x3 cells if 
to talk that the max size is 4x4 cells (as it described here: 
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html#sizes). 
Even if I'll define exact layout_width and layout_height in my widget 
layouts in dip it will still take 4x3 cells, just it's visible part 
will have another size.

Answer (score 2):

Well, looks like emulator not always refresh my app and that is why I saw my old dimensions instead of new. My friend also said that emulator usually doesn't update apps if using startActivityForResult. So in that case it is better to restart widget manually. Hope that will be helpfull for someone else :)

Comment: The emulators have a few things they do differently than real devices, especially with app widgets.  I've spent many hours chasing my tail, because an emulator was doing something odd with an app widget.  I've learned to mostly not use the emulators for app widget development, or at least at the first sign of something unexpected, to see what happens on a real device.

Answer (score 0):

From http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html

> Because the Home screen's layout orientation (and thus, the cell sizes) can change, as a rule of thumb, you should assume the worst-case cell size of 74 pixels for the height and width of a cell. However, you must subtract 2 from the final dimension to account for any integer rounding errors that occur in the pixel count. To find your minimum width and height in density-independent pixels (dp), use this formula:
> (number of cells * 74) - 2

Comment: Bruce, but android:minHeight="146dip" is exactly 2*74-2 and android:minWidth="220dip" is 3*74-2. And as I understand in xml/widget.xml we describe a parent object dimension. So when in widget_layout.xml I use fill_parent for Height and Width I expect they will relate to defined in xml/widget.xml.

Comment: I just can not understand why if my widget's parent should be 3*2 cells the widget takes 4*3 cells. Looks like some kind of "a snark". Trying another width and height values. Any ideas on that problem?

Comment: @Alexey +1 I too have the same problem trying to get a height of 1 row. Ended up setting the min height to 40dp and it now fits into 1 row.